# Invalid Drm Argument Exception Validating App Store Receipt

Tags: php, ios, swift, appstore-sandbox

```
let url = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!
let receipt = NSData(contentsOf: url)?.base64EncodedString(options: [])
```

The `receipt` string works well when I send it to Apple servers, but when my server sends it i get this error:

> "status":21002, "exception":"com.apple.its.drm.InvalidDrmArgumentException"

I have no clue why, especially since it was working yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the HTTP POST function variables were all being sent to APPLE.

I had thought the receipt=XXX&key=1234 were separated in the PHP Server side code.

But the '&' wasn't there so the receipt sent to Apple was XXXkey=1234

so com.apple.its.drm.InvalidDrmArgumentException means that the receipt data has an error/ extra data.